# Are there regional differences among GPS modules?

Tags: gps

Are there any regional differences between GPS modules? Let's say I wanted to buy Canon GP-ES 2, but it is not available in the Czech Republic. So I wonder if I buy it elsewhere if it works the same - I guess i.e. the same amount of satellites will be purchased by Canon. Or will work at all, because Canon had a shorter license for satellite services?

Comment: No individual company owns the GPS network. Licenses do not apply at consumer level. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17535/why-is-gps-a-free-service

Comment: Well, I read somewhere that the quality of finding a position on the map in cell phones depends on how many satellites the company has purchased. If GPS is free, this information must be incorrect and problems with identifying a good location for some cell phones will be than in hardware for example. Then also my question would be ready to close. But If I ask about a number of satellites for a product in Google I can still get some pages so it doesn't look to be incorrect.

Comment: The satellites are up there for everyone to see & use. The limitation is purely one of line of sight. Open countryside, you can see 10 satellites, built up areas, one or two… & geo-positioning is likely to fail. GPS is not very robust in inner cities, because the view of the sky is limited. By the same token, it doesn't work indoors & not so well in vehicles. The satellites are constantly on the move, relative to the ground, so accurate date/time-keeping is vital, so it knows which is which & where it should be.

Comment: BTW, phones only use GPS if they can't find anything better. They will choose WiFi & phone masts above GPS.

Comment: @Tetsujin, last versions of android "balance" the usage with (mostly) GPS and mobile towers (coordinates of these towers). And this is because (w/o data communication) to get gps satellites trajectories take up to 5-6 minutes via GPS signal.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - GPS is useless indoors, so this 'balance' needs to be carefully juggled. [I've never used Android, have no clue how they work.] I got my first GPS device 20 years ago [& added a separate car roof arial + booster very shortly after], first iPhone 15 years ago… still don't really know how it all works under the hood ;) I travelled the world with both over the years & they 'just work'.

Comment: @Tetsujin, correct, indoor is out of question. But accuracy can be broken because of many factors like signal blockage, reflections, jamming, solar storms.

Comment: Think what would happen to a legitimate American user of this device when he travelled to Czech Republic. Oops, we didn't purchase satellites for this area, no service for you? Even if this were true, you would not be worse off buying a GPS device abroad. Unlike some other market-local devices, this is a device _designed_ to travel; reducing its capabilities locally would reduce its usefulness for _everyone_.

Comment: @Juandev my guess is that there is some confusion based on issues with "overseas" phones having issues with "local" GPS performance (here is [one example](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/mi-10-poor-gps-in-europe-after-switching-from-global-to-xiaomi-eu-stable.64469/)). In the past I had similar issues, but they were always resolvable by updating a certain config file which made the phone find GPS satellites easier. My expectation is that a less complex device (compared to a phone) such as the Canon GP-ES 2 is not tailored to specific markets and you should not have any issues.

Comment: @Juandev another point that makes me think there is no regional difference: the firmware from e.g. the [Hong Kong site](https://hk.canon/en/support/GP-E2/model) is identical to that from the [Dutch site](https://www.canon.nl/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/accessories_battery_grips_etc/gp-e2.html). If there was any difference in GPS configuration I would expect to see a difference in firmware.

Comment: Even if GPS receivers are colloquially still called so (GPS was the first, but now just one of many satellite navigation systems), the more correct generic term is 'GNSS receiver' as most models combine data from multiple other systems to increase accuracy. Even if the basic navigation networks have mostly global coverage, the receiver may also support enhancement services (A-GNSS and SBAS are often used) and these services are not necessarily global, but can be restricted to specific countries or regions.

Comment: The  Canon GP-ES 2 seem indeed only to use GPS and not even other satellite systems like Galileo, GLONASS or BeiDou and should work just as well (or poor) all around the world. Other GNSS receivers may however very well at least show poorer performance if they are used in other regions than where they were sold, as they may not be able to use enhancement services, which only are available in the market or region where they were originally sold.

Comment: Well, I have already purchased Canon GP-ES 2 from Japan so we will see.

Answer (score 1):

GPS is a public and free service. So Canon do not own satellites nor need license to use them.

Same is true (AFAIK) about Galileo, GLONASS, BeiDou and local as QZSS, IRNSS.

Check [here](https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/space/) for more reference about civil signals/users.

And quoting [this](https://www.gps.gov/policy/legislation/uscode/#title10):

> The statute directs the Secretary of Defense to provide civil GPS
> service on a **continuous, worldwide basis, free of direct user fees**.

Comment: No "direct user fee" but the "fee" is paid by the GPS chip manufacturer, so it is paid by the camera manufacturer and eventually by the end-user.

Comment: @xenoid, I am not sure because all the documentation is available for free. Yes, manufacturer pay for the chip and antenna. But this is not a limitation in sense of preciseness and satellites reachability.

Comment: Also, the DoD can decrease the accuracy of civil GPS over designated areas (which is why there are Galileo/Glonass).

Comment: @xenoid. "In May 2000, at the direction of President Bill Clinton, the U.S. government ended its use of Selective Availability in order to make GPS more responsive to civil and commercial users worldwide. " Bottom right of this page: https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yet I have seen areas in Europe, which are marked by signs to lack GPS and I don't think these were installed prior to 2000.

Comment: @Juandev, do you have first hand experience? And as I wrote in other comment: "accuracy can be broken because of many factors like signal blockage, reflections, jamming, solar storms..."